# Perform animations on custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

I'm trying to animate a few items in a custom `UITableViewCell` when a user presses a button in the cell. I have set `addTarget`: and added a method to animate the items in the cell. I've set a tag for the button so I can get the index. In the method, I call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: to get the cell the button was called on. I'm casting the object returned by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: to my custom cell. After I have the custom cell, I perform the animations on the objects. The problem is the animations aren't happening. When I try setting a property on one of the items in the cell, it doesn't work either. The custom cell is not returning nil so I'm not sure of the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I'm using to call the animations

```
-(void)favButtonPressed:(id)sender{        
FavoritesCell *favCell = (FavoritesCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    favCell.picButton.alpha = 0.5;
}  completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using to call the animations

Comment: Might want to print our your index path row to make sure you actually have the correct indexPath for the cell you pressed on.

Comment: @Zhang I have checked it. The index is correct.

Answer (score 0):

One way u can do it by using custom delegate like below, hope this helps u .

i took an example of your case go through this hope this helps u

in custom cell calss define delegate protocol like below
in `FavoritesCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class FavoritesCell;

@protocol CellActionDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)doAnimationForCell:(FavoritesCell *)cell forButton:(UIButton *)picButton; //in this u can pass the cell itself
@end

@interface FavoritesCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic,retain)UIButton *picButton; //i am doing a simple test, say this is your pic button
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<CellActionDelegate>cellDelegate;
@end
```

and in `FavoritesCell.m` file

```
#import "FavoritesCell.h"

@implementation FavoritesCell
@synthesize cellDelegate;
@synthesize picButton = _picButton;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (self) {
      // Initialization code
      _picButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 3, 100, 100)];
      //set the property // for test

      [_picButton addTarget:self action:@selector(favButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [_picButton.layer setCornerRadius:50];
      [_picButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
      [_picButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]];
      [_picButton.layer setBorderWidth:5];
      _picButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
      [self.contentView addSubview:_picButton];
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated  
{
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

 // Configure the view for the selected state
}   

- (void)favButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
   //or you can do the animation hear only no need to delegate to controller form cell

   if([self.cellDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doAnimationForCell:forButton:)])
   {
      [self.cellDelegate doAnimationForCell:self forButton:sender]; //call this method
   }
}

@end
```

in `ViewController.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FavoritesCell.h" //import it

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,CellActionDelegate> //confirms to delegate

 //.... other stuffs
```

in ViewController.m file

```
 //...other stuffs

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return 5;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FavoritesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];
   if(cell == nil)
   {
      cell = [[FavoritesCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];

   }

   cell.cellDelegate = self; //set the deleagte to this class
   [cell.picButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Two-Red-Flower-.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //set it hear or in custom cell itself
   //...other logics

   return cell;

}  

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return 130.0f;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


} 

//define the delegate method
- (void)doAnimationForCell:(FavoritesCell *)cell forButton:(UIButton *)picButton //this the picButton
{

   //you can get index path of cell
   //you can get the tapped button of the cell
   //then do your animation
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
      picButton.alpha = 0.5;
    }  completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
-(void)favButtonPressed:(id)sender
{        
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView];

    // or try this one alternatively if the above line give wrong indexPath
    //CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:((UIButton *)sender).center toView:self.myTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    // I assume "self" here is your view controller 
    FavoritesCell *favCell = (FavoritesCell *)[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        favCell.picButton.alpha = 0.5;
    }  completion:nil];
}
```